# Is the set of all Idempotent matrix in $M_n(\mathbb{F})$ linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, idempotents

Is the set $I:=\{\text{set of all Idempotent matrix in}\ M_n(\mathbb{F})\}$ linearly independent?

**My thought:** I think the answer is no if $\mathbb{F}$ is infinite.
If $\mathbb{F}$ is infinite then the class of all idempotent matrix is infinite. Any subset of $I$ with more than $n^2$ elements is not linearly independent [as dim($M_n(\mathbb{F}))=n^2$]. As $\mathbb{F}$ is infinite hence $I$ is infinite.

But what about if $\mathbb{F}$ is finite?

Comment: How do you know there are infinitely many idempotent matrices?

Comment: If $\mathbb{F}$ is infinite then $GL_n{\mathbb{(F)}}$ is infinite, because for each $a\in \mathbb{F}$ $A_{a}:=a.I$ is a member of $Gl_n(\mathbb{F})$. Also the matrix $B:=[e_1;0;...;0]$ is idempotent which is not in the center of the ring $M_n(\mathbb{F})$. Therefore for all $a \in \mathbb{F},\ A_aBA_a^{-1}$ is idempotent. Hence there are infinitely many idempotent matrices in $M_n(\mathbb{F})$ if $\mathbb{F}$ is infinite.

Comment: Don't we have $A_a B A_a^{-1} = B$?

Comment: I cannot think of any answer. Can you please provide me some hint?

Comment: I can't see a reason that it has to be true in general, but I haven't thought of a counterexample yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** If $A$ is idempotent then so is $I-A$. Moreover, $I$ is idempotent.

**Note** The problem contains a small trap, you need to make sure that there exists at least one other idempotent matrix besides $I$. This happens excepting when $n=..$?

Comment: I think excepting when n=1. Correct?

Answer (score 4):

Of course not:  $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}+ \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ for any ring used as coefficients.

Comment: But what if $n=1$?

Comment: @N.S.  You're speaking as if one had to provide a counterexample for all $n$ to disprove a claim quantifying for all $n$. Of course one only needs to provide a counterexample for one particular $n$, and so I have. One could interpret it as being claimed for one unspecified $n$, but that seems overly pedantic. Clearly you're not ignorant of another easy counterexample for $n=1$.   So i'm asking: does the above comment really have a purpose?

Comment: Yes, the comment has a purpose. For a problem like this the answer I would expect from my students is "The set it linearly independent/dependent when $n=...$"

Comment: @N.S. Glad I'm not under any obligation to answer questions according to other people's preferred interpretations! Frankly ancientmathematician did a better job than both of us in terms of the most flexible answer.

Comment: If that is your interpretation, then the OP already answered the question: any infinite $\mathbb F$ will do.

Comment: @N.S. Ye gods, it's just all $\forall$ or all $\exists$ with you, I guess. I will spell it out because apparently(?) my interpretation wasn't as transparent as I thought. My interpretation was this: "if $F$ is a given field, is it necessarily true that the idempotents of $M_n(F)$ are linearly independent?" and then all the OP's thoughts make sense.  The comment about there being infinitely many idempotents suggests the OP had $n>1$ in mind, but I agree that whether or not that was an oversight or not would only be something the OP could answer.

Comment: Said another way, I felt $n$ was the only thing which was at liberty to be chosen. Not the $n$'s *and* the field.

Answer (score 3):

$O^2=O$, and so is idempotent. No set containing the zero "vector" is linearly independent.

Comment: Shoulda thought of that :)